# Trying to print a value of a variable by using classes in Python. But a error pops up An error pops up unsupported operand type(s) for 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, string, class, oop, average

```
class Student:

    #Static variable
    school = 'vailankanni'

    def __init__(self, m1 , m2, m3):
        self.m1 = m1
        self.m2 = m2
        self.m3 = m3

    def avg(self):
        return (self.m1 + self.m2 + self.m3) /3

         



s1 = Student('20', '40', '60')
s2 = Student('80', '100', '120')

print(s1.avg())
```

By printing s1.avg() I should get the details from s1 variable but all I get is
**An error pops up unsupported operand type(s) for 'str' and 'int'.**

How should I fix this?

Comment: Remove the quotes around your numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the values as string objects.
Instead use

```
s1 = Student(20,40,60) #without the quotes
s1.avg()
```

Comment: Thanks for solving it.